# Android - How to update my recyclerview from another fragment in a viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, spinner

So I've got 2 fragments in a tablayout. I used viewpager to set it up. 
In the first fragment I have a recyclerview filled with data. In the second fragment I have a spinner.
When the user selects something in the spinner the recyclerview should be updated with the new data according to the selection.
How can I achieve that in the second fragment the user selects an option from the spinner than he swipes back to the first fragment and the recyclerview is updated already with the new data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways:

1. Use an
   [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
   and put some extra in it:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("foo",somevalue);
   ```

   then send it with

   [sendBroadcast(intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent))

   Your receiver class has just to extends the
   [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
   Class and update the data in the
   [onReceive](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))
   method.

   ```
   public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //manipulate your data
      }
   }
   ```

   Remember to register your receiver
2. Use a [Singleton Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that contains your data. So you can set the data from the first fragment (after the spinner selection) and get it from your second fragment (in the [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `RecyclerView`'s adapter and the list of data in the parent activity instead of the fragment. In `onItemSelected()` of the `Spinner`, call `adapter.notifyDatasetchanged` (or `notifyItem(Range)Inserted/Changed/Removed()`).

If you have lots of inter-fragment communication a very easy way to accomplish this will be to implement EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Register both fragments on the EventBus, and when an item is selected in the spinner of Fragment B, send a SpinnerItemSelected event. Fragment A will receive it if it's registered on the bus and you can call `notifyDatasetChanged()` upon receiving it.